# Map a route to the same controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I want only one controller action to handle all GETs.  How can I map a route to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.MapRoute("AllGETs",
    "{*any}",
    new { Controller = "YourController", Action = "YourAction" },
    new { HttpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

Comment: Hmm...that doesn't seem to work.  I browse to localhost:4075/NewAccount and get a Resource not Found.

Comment: If your action has parameters (for example `string id`) add defaults to the route: `new { Controller = ..., Id = "" }`

Comment: And try to put this route to the top of your RouteTable

Comment: Don't forget that the controller value is the type name of the controller sans "Controller". So if you have "FooController" then the route should have new {Controller="Foo", Action = "ActionMethodName"}

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up doing this, seemed to do what I needed:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    // Route name
    "Default",             
    // URL with parameters
    "{controller}/{id}",   
    // Parameter defaults
    new {controller = "Home", action = "GenericPostHandler", id = "" }
);
```